# Communication between the two servers to transfer data

Tags: php, connection, database-connection

Why can not establish a connection!! How to create a relationship between two tables in two database on separate server for information
In fact, I want to get records from a table in second server and insert to another server in the table
Table selection is correct:site1.com.class.users

---

this is my code:

```
$conn_server1=mysql_connect("site1.com","user","pass");
$db_server1=mysql_select_db("class",$conn_server1);

$conn_server2=mysql_connect("site2.com","user","pass");
$db_server2=mysql_select_db("class",$conn_server2);

$result=mysql_query("select * from site2.com.class.users where site2.com.class.users.mobile not in(select mobile form site1.com.class.users)",$conn_server1);

while(mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
mysql_query("insert into site1.com.class.users(name,family,phone1,phone2,mobile) select name,family,phone1,phone2,mobile from
site2.com.class.users",$conn_server1); 
    site2.com.class.users",$conn_server1);
```

Comment: You would probably be better looking into something like [mysqldump](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/mysqldump.html)

Comment: First, you should stop using mysql extension and use mysqli instead, or PDO. Now to answer your question, we may need to see the error message your scrips throws (if it's configured to dislay errors)

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to select data from connection 1 while using the connection 2. That's not going to work. And while you are at it. You might want to look into using [MysqlI](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php) / [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) instead of the marked as deprecated mysql extension.

```
$res_server = mysql_query("SELECT name, family, phone1, phone2, mobile FROM users", $conn_server2);

while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($res_server)) {
   // update / insert into on $conn_server1
}
```

Comment: I think you just do not understand my question. I want to communicate between two servers to transfer data. NOT operation on a server

Comment: You just wrote the code that record are read from the server, it is convenient to do so. Would include what I have written inside the "while".